# Как работает transform-style?

Tags: html, css, transform

Как я понимаю, `transform-style: preserve-3d;` задается непосредственно самому элементу и "включает" у него 3д пространство. Но лично я совершенно не вижу разницы с использованием `transform-style: preserve-3d;` и без использования `transform-style: preserve-3d;`.

У меня есть два примера:

1. Используется `transform-style: preserve-3d;`– у элемента есть свое 3д пространство;

```css
.parent {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.child:hover {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

2. Не используется `transform-style: preserve-3d;` – у элемента нет своего 3д пространства;

   ```css
   .parent {
     width: 60%;
     height: 300px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
     perspective: 600px;
   }

   .child {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background: yellowgreen;
     display: inline-block;
     transform: rotateY(45deg);
   }

   .child:hover {
     transform: rotateX(-360deg);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
   ```

В чем разница? Выглядят два примера совершенно одинаково. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Там сложнее. Попробуй пересечь два трансформированных элемента, причём, я не уверен, на ком должен стоять `preserve-3d` - есть подозрение, что на родителе.

Answer (score 0):

Свойство transform-style CSS определяет положение дочернего элемента в 3D-пространстве или в той же плоскости, что и родительский элемент. `flat` -  показывает, что дочерний элемент лежит в той же плоскости, что и родительский.  `preserve-3d` - показывает, что дочерний элемент должен быть спозиционирован в 3D-пространстве.

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


.div2 {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: silver;
  animation: 5s infinite example;
  transform-style: flat;
}
.div2.pres {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.div3 {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
}

@keyframes example {
   0% { transform: rotateX(  0deg) rotateY(  0deg); }
  25% { transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY( 90deg); }
  50% { transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(180deg); }
  75% { transform: rotateX(540deg) rotateY(270deg); }
 100% { transform: rotateX(720deg) rotateY(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2 pres">
    <div class="div3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```